# androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog always changing from activity layout to white background

Tags: android, android-camera, android-alertdialog, zxing

My alertdialog is always changing the activity layout to a white page. The dialog is coming up while using the camera. Tried changing background to transparent with no luck. Any ideas? attached screenshot from emulator. Want the alertdialog to appear while the camera is in use, not having a white background covering the whole screen.

Code:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                //set icon
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                //set title
                .setTitle("Kan ikke finne produktet i databasen")
                //set message
                .setMessage("Vil du søke manuelt?")
                // Background
                //set positive button
                .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, ManualActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                //set negative button
                .setNegativeButton("Nei", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);                        }
                })

                .show();
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:zxing_framing_rect_width="225dp"
        app:zxing_framing_rect_height="275dp"
        />

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ViewfinderView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
        app:zxing_possible_result_points="#FFC300"
        app:zxing_viewfinder_laser="#EA1818"
        app:zxing_result_view="#2DA818"
        app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_mask"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
        android:text="@string/barcode_help"
        android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text"
        />

</merge>
```

[Screenshot from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDwVg.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your activity xml file?

Comment: Added xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `setView` instruction to your alert dialog.

```
.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
```

Assuming your xml file name's `dialog_layout` otherwise change it for the correct one.

Comment: This makes the dialog dissapear and the app crashes on the second attempt to trigger trigger the dialog. The activity got 2 views, using the zxing scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help you

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: This is what i tried before, but its just giving me a "cannot resovle method" error

Comment: This worked: 
            this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

**BUT** the background is now black, as if the camera is not running in the background.

Comment: try to change the background color from  Color.TRANSPARENT to any other

Comment: Background is changing with any other color as well.